# How to submit inputs as an array jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="tagType1">
    <input id="tag1" name="tagType1" value="tag1" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="tag2" name="tagType1" value="tag2" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="tag3" name="tagType1" value="tag3" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="tag4" name="tagType1" value="tag4" type="checkbox" />
</div>

<div id="tagType2">
    <input id="tag5" name="tagType2" value="tag5" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="tag6" name="tagType2" value="tag6" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="tag7" name="tagType2" value="tag7" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="tag8" name="tagType2" value="tag8" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
 $.get($("#filter form").attr("action") + "/count", function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#workCount span').text(data.toString());
    });
```

And the following method:

```
public JsonResult Count(string[] tagType1 = null, string[] tagType2 = null)
{
    // Do something
}
```

My question is, how do I group the inputs from my two  containers within jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use $(":input").serializeArray();

.serializeArray() Returns: Array

it Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values.

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 0):

you  can use    `traditional: true`

```
string[] tagType1 = //ALL OF THE TAG ONE COLLECTIONS 
string[] tagType2 = //ALL OF THE TAG TWO COLLECTIONS 

var params = { data2: tagType1, data2: tagType2 };
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "yoururl",
            data: params,
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        });
```

Action:

```
public JsonResult Count(string[] data1, string[] data2)
{
    // Do something
}
```